# contenteditable="true" not functional in a sub component Angular

Tags: html, angular, contenteditable

I have a div with a contenteditable="true" property in a component.

subcomponent html:

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" >
</div>
```

.
Main component html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <app-subcomponent
            [someValue]="someValue">
        </app-subcomponent>
    </body>
</html>
```

It does result in the standard blue outline as expected but it is not editable. However if I would add the div with the contenteditable property inside the main component it works fine.

Why is this the case and how can I solve it? I can use the input and textarea elements (and they work) but I would prefer the div editable method because it would be a more elegant solution in this case.

Comment: **[It seems to work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmctn5?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**, so maybe you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I know that I have done it before without issues so maybe it's indeed because my specific case, I will go ahead and isolate the section of the code while maintain the problem.

Comment: Please give us a sandbox to verify that you indeed have this issue.

Comment: I one by one commented all my code and found that the command:
jQuery(".freeSelect").disableSelection();
Resulted in this behavior.
Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

The issues was outside of this part of the code:
I had the jQuery(".freeSelect").disableSelection(); somewhere and it only acted on the subcommponent and not my main component